# Conductance of random walk on a square

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, markov-chains

Let the conductance profile of a random walk, $\phi(u)$, be defined as:

$$\phi_S:=\frac{Q(S,S^c)}{\pi(S)}, \phi(u):=\inf_{S:\pi(S)\leq u} \phi_S$$

where $S\subset \Omega$, $\Omega$ is a finite state space, $Q(S,S^c)=\sum_{x\in S,y\in S^c}\pi(x)P(x,y)$ and $\pi$ the stationary distribution of a random walk.

> Now consider a lazy random walk on a $n\times n$ square i.e. there is a holding probability of $1/2$ at each state state and the walk moves to nearest neighbors with equal probability. There is a claim in a [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjGsKXPp_PqAhUZJzQIHbIHDKgQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2Fmath%2F0305349&usg=AOvVaw0LK-2TZDrbn-51GLOfpToK)(Page $249$, Example $1$)I'm reading that for $0\leq u\leq 1/2$, which I don't understand why? :
> $$\phi(u)\geq\frac{a}{n\sqrt{u}}$$
> where $a$ is a constant.

My attempt: Let $u=1/2$, we cut the square into two almost equal pieces by a vertical line segment and consider one of the pieces to be $S$. $\pi$ is uniform and so I see that for this specific $S$, $Q(S,S^c)=O(1/n)$ but am not sure why it is also true for the $S$ that minimizes $\phi_S$ in the definition of $\phi(u)$ and also not sure where we are getting $\sqrt{u}$ from?

Comment: Is the domain actually a torus rather than a square? If not then $\pi$ is *not* uniform.

Comment: Are you sure that you're reading the paper correctly?  It looks to me like $\phi_S \in [0,1]$ but the lower bound listed is unbounded as $u \to 0$.

Comment: @Ian It is a square and not a torus. I see, my attempt is wrong then. If $\pi$ is uniform for lazy walk on a line segment, I thought it would be so on a square too.

Comment: @MarcusM True, the paper had for $1\leq u \leq 1/2$, so I thought it was a typo and it is $0\leq u\leq 1/2$ instead. Added paper now.

Comment: @Ian I see why it's not uniform because degree is not $4$ for boundary vertices but should be close to uniform.

Comment: Considering both the definition of $\Phi$ and the bound (6), it seems that the inequality is originally intended to be true for $u\in[\pi^*,\frac{1}{2}]$ (where $\pi^*=\min\pi$), although it is still not obvious to me why the inequality holds true.

Comment: @SangchulLee True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q(S,S^c)$ can be interpreted as the boundary of the set $S$ and $\pi(S)$ as it's volume. One needs to convince themselves that the minimum in the definition of $\phi(u)$ happens for a square. If we know that, then the volume of the square set $S$ for which minimum is attained, in the definition of $\phi(u)$, is $n^2\times u$ assuming $\pi$ is uniform ($\pi$ is in fact almost uniform) and the boundary or surface area is $4n\times \sqrt{u}$ and thus

$$\phi(u)\geq \frac{4n\times \sqrt{u}}{n^2\times u}=\frac{a}{n\sqrt{u}}$$

Comment: Isoperimetric inequality would be exactly what justifies this argument, although I am no expert on this topic to tell anything affirmative. If I remember correctly, this is also related to the spectral gap, which might possibly help resolve this case as well. (For instance, Theorem 6.15 of *Lyons and Peres* relates $\phi_S(1/2)$ to the spectral gap.)